# Repeat binary number to be the same length as another number in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary

Say I have a binary number message of `0100110101100101` and a binary key of `001`.

How can I repeat the key to be the same length as the message? As in take the length of the message and then repeat the pattern of the key till the length of the message is reached?

In the example the output should be `0010010010010010`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use python's `list slicing`:

```
In [1599]: a = '0100110101100101'
In [1602]: key = '001'

In [1608]: factor = len(a) // len(key)
In [1606]: remainder = len(a) % len(key)

In [1625]: if factor == 0:
      ...:     print("pattern greater than the string")
      ...: else:
      ...:     answer = (key * factor) + key[:remainder]
      ...: 

In [1614]: answer
Out[1614]: '0010010010010010'
```

Comment: Mayank, this solution prints the string even when the pattern is smaller than the string. Maybe it will be good to add a condition if needed by @Sulhan!

Comment: @Ananth Updated my solution to handle key is greater than message case. Thanks.